# Using AT commands in PHP script on MacOS

Tags: php, macos, sms-gateway

I'm working on a PHP script that could send and receive SMS on my mac, using a HUAWEI GSM modem.
First I tried to use AT commands directly in the Terminal and I succeeded. Here are the command lines I use to do it :

Verifying on which ports is my Huawei modem :
ls -al /dev/tty.*

Opening a AT command session :
screen /dev/tty.HUAWEIMobile-Modem 115200

Then I can use AT commands and it works fine.
But as I am a newbee with Terminal, I don't understand why I have to use a screen command to open the AT command session (I found it on a webpage and it works, but why ? ).
And what if I would like to open this AT command session without using a screen command ?

Then I switch to my PHP script. I try to use a very nice one I found on this page (http://gonzalo123.com/2011/03/21/howto-sendread-smss-using-a-gsm-modem-at-commands-and-php/) and which is known to work fine on Linux. So it should also work on MacOS isn't it ?

This script first ask for the device, so I gave it that, according to the command I used to open the AT command session in the Terminal :
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/tty.HUAWEIMobile-Modem");

When I launch the script, it returns this error :
Warning: Specified serial port is not valid in /Users/iMac1/Documents/MAMP/SMSing/solution 2/sms/serial.php on line 72

So I check line 72 where is the first command using the $device variable. Error here is logical. The command :
$this->_exec("stty -F " . $device)

I find it strange because of the -F parameter.
So I tried to change it for :
$this->_exec("stty -f " . $device)

Then when I launch my script, it does nothing and even never ends.

I get stuck here.
Could someone help me ?

Thank you in advance
Louis

Comment: how/where are you running this php script? from the command line, or via webserver? If it's via webserver, the webserver is unlikely to have the rights to access /dev devices directly.

Comment: Interesting.. quite long question though :)

Comment: I run my php script from my local Apache server provided by MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Use phpserial class that is on  http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/17926.html using the code below.

But i strongly recommend using Python and Gammu for this instead of PHP. PHP is not designed for OS operations. Python does.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$time = time();
$mensaje = "Hola este es un mensaje desde Mac ".$time;
$pais = "+58";
$numero = "00__myphone__00";



include "../php_serial.class.php";
$serial = new phpSerial();
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/tty.HUAWEIMobile-Modem");
$serial->deviceOpen('r+');
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);

$serial->sendMessage("AT+CMGF=1\r",1);
$serial->readPort();

$serial->sendMessage('AT+CMGS="'.$pais.$numero.'"'."\r",1);
echo $serial->readPort();

$serial->sendMessage($mensaje."\r",1);
echo $serial->readPort();

$serial->sendMessage("\x1a",2);
echo $serial->readPort();

// If you want to change the configuration, the device must be closed
$serial->deviceClose();

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the php_serial.class.php you're talking about can't work on Mac considering it's explicitly designed for Linux and Windows. So I tried to add commands to make it work on Mac, and it looks like the problem comes from stty Terminal command.
If I run a stty in Terminal, it works as expected, but if I run a stty -f in Terminal, it does as if a port is opened and wait for something else until I close it with a Ctrl-Z. Considering Mac Terminal doesn't recognize -F stty option, I think that the problem comes from stty. Let me try to look at Python as you advised me...

Comment: Ok, I have checked php_serial.class.php and found the problematic PHP command :
$this->_dHandle = fopen($this->_device, $mode);
It makes the script never reach its end.
I tried to replace fopen with file_get_contents. Then the script reach its end, but the file is not open anymore.
Any idea ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I used the code above and worked for me 100% i have a SMS&Voice App Company in Venezuela and i Use Python/Django/Sqlite/Gammu and other technologies. But i Wanted to try with PHP and it's not the best solution. Putup a VM machine with linux with Fusion and install the usb-modeswitch and try gammu from the console. its super easy anything i cand do to help. please let me know.

Comment: Hello eddwinpaz
The problem for me is that I had never worked with Linux, Python and Gammu. I'm going to check out how it works. Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the porpuse of using a Phone with PHP? Fun or work??? if its is for fun it would be less painfull to try it with Python and Gammu than is to PHP/Mac php is not designed to work for low lever OS

Comment: It is for work, but I have no obligation to use PHP. I only made this choice because I write PHP scripts every week. I had downloaded Python and began a tuto. It doesn't look like very hard...

Comment: Its not hard at all.. you should see the gammu library for python its a different world working Telecom with python believe me I have suffered pain with other language trying to figure it out in the past

Comment: Ok, I'm able to execute a stty command from a Python script. Now, I have a question : when I am in the Terminal and want to execute AT commands, I use a screen command to connect to my modem. But in Python, using that screen command doesn't seem to work :

cmd=os.popen("screen /dev/tty.HUAWEIModile-Modem 115200")
cmd.read()

And the answer is : 'Must be connected to a terminal.\n'

May be if I could open the connection in the Terminal without using screen command, I could successfully do the same from my Python script ? But how to do this ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

this is a script for python to send a SMS without problems. For this you need to install Gammu and using the console configurate the USB Dongle you want to use. Solving it purely with python is not the best way. see the code below is a working sample to execute this ( python sms.py ) on the console.

sms.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gammu
import sys

sm = gammu.StateMachine()
sm.ReadConfig(2) #is gammu config
sm.Init()

to = '+5844444'
body = 'Your message'

message = {
   'Text': body,
   'SMSC': {'Location': 1},
   'Number': to,
}

try:
  # Send SMS if all is OK
  sm.SendSMS(message)
  print 'Success, SMS was Sent'

except gammu.ERR_UNKNOWN:
   # Show error if message not sent
   print 'Error, SMS not Sent'
```

Comment: Thank you very much eddwinpaz. I've installed gammu on my Mac following a good tutorial on back2arie.wordpress.com. But there's something wrong, cause when I try import gammu, I get : ImportError: No module named 'gamma'
Any idea about this ?

Comment: The tuto's owner told me that gammu command shall be run from anywhere. But when I try it, I get a "command not found". Obviously, gammu did not install correctly.

Comment: Hi eddwinpaz. Did you encounter difficulties when installing gammu ? I tried it a second time this morning with version 1.33, I get few warnings on configuring and making and finally everything looks ok. But when I try to run gammu it still returns "command not found". And of course if I try to import gammu in Python, I get "No module named 'gammu'". Please help.

Comment: Not at all.. you need to make a config profile. go to terminal and type ( sudo gammu config )  then get the USB you need and save it and when calling the config it will lookup the default config wich is the one you set up. this will make the picture more clear. http://en.doc.centreon.com/HowToSendSMSWithGammu this one also https://drupal.org/node/1806030

Comment: Do you mean that a bad configuration could make gammu not work at all ? I don't think so. When I try "sudo gammu config", it get the same "gammu: command not found". The problem obviously occurs on installation, not (or not yet) in configuration

Comment: try sudo gammu --config

Comment: you can get all parameters on sudo gammu --help